# Considering a newer question about judges' appointments

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

If I ask a new question about the early Shofetim (ie., pre-BH"M), will that be a dupe of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18866/5)? What about "in biblical times" (to include the early Shofetim and also the era of Bayith Rishon, since the answer covers Bayith Sheni)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions you propose are not the same as the existing question, and answers to the existing question needn't also answer your proposed questions. So, it seems clear to me that the questions you propose would be related to, but not dupes of, the existing question.

Comment: Are you sure the other question doesn't also cover B"R?

Comment: So edit that one to make it explicitly about the B"Sh.  Then the way is clear for you.